# Python Regex - extracting multiple sentences containing same keyword

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

regex = r"[^.?!-]*(?<=[.?\s!-])\b(pfs)\b(?=[\s.?!-])[^.?!-]*[.?!-]"

test_str = "pfs alert conf . it is unlikely that we will sign it - pfs of $ 950 filed to driver - we are gathering information"

subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

As we see, test_str has two sentences having keyword 'pfs'. However, the above python code can only extract second sentence ' pfs of $ 950 filed to driver', how to modify it to extract 'pfs alert conf' as well?

Comment: Is the keyword always at the beginning of the sentences?

Comment: not necessary. In this case, it just happens at the beginning. So I want to a more generalized script to be able to extract sentence when keyword is at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `pfs` is at the start of the line but in your positive lookbehind you are matching 1 character with `(?<=[.?\s!-])` You might use an alternation to assert either the start of the line `^` or `[^.?!-]*(?<=[.?\s!-])`

`(?:^|[^.?!-]*(?<=[.?\s!-]))\bpfs\b(?=[\s.?!-])[^.?!-]*[.?!-]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aVhye4/1)

[Demo python](http://rextester.com/PALNN13383)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/) instead, imo it is really better suited here:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize

test_str = "pfs alert conf . it is unlikely that we will sign it - pfs of $ 950 filed to driver - we are gathering information. some junky words thereafter"
sentences = [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(test_str) if "pfs" in sent]
print(sentences)
```

This yields (mind the missing last sentence without `pfs`):

```
['pfs alert conf .', 
 'it is unlikely that we will sign it - pfs of $ 950 filed to driver - we are gathering information.']
```